# Update a table with values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, dml

I have a table (say,ABC) which has the following structure :

```
 COMP_CODE    NAME    SALARY  SID1
-------------------------------------
  NULL      Alex     42000     85
  NULL      Alex     42000     89
  NULL      Alex     42000     96
  NULL      Alex     42000    100
  NULL      Alex     42000     52
```

I want to update the _**COMP_CODE**_ column in the above table from value residing in another table **(CC)**. The matching columns among the two table is ***SID1***. The structure of *CC* is as follows :

```
  COMP_CODE    SID1
----------------------
    0AA         85
    0AB         96
    0CD         98
    0DE         72
    0EH        100
```

Can this achieved through a ***CURSOR*** or any other sort of method.

Comment: You can use direct query to update ABC table. Why to use cursor?

Comment: It's easy when there is one `comp_code` for each `sid1`. But which do You want for `96`? Minimum, maximum, first unused? Please explain and show expected output.

Comment: @ManojKumarRai I want to update the whole set of data in a single go, that's why!

Comment: @PonderStibbons I have edited the data of the _**CC**_ table. Please have a look and provide some solution to the problem if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO ABC t1
USING (select SID,max(COMP_CODE) COMP_CODE from CC GROUP BY SID) t2
ON (t1.SID1= t2.SID1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET t1.COMP_CODE    = t2.COMP_CODE
```

Comment: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: Oops I didn't see you had multiple values in CC. That's what gives the error. You have to choose which value to use. I've edited the query to give an option.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think I made a hasty decision in  choosing the correct answer for the question. After a bit of pondering over solution through the  _**MERGE**_ technique, I can say that it is way more sensible and meaningful. Appreciate everyone's effort though.

Comment: @@SørenKongstad Thank You. This makes so much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no need to store the data twice.  You can just fetch it using a `JOIN` when you need it.

You can update the values as:

```
update abc
    set comp_code = (select cc.comp_code
                     from cc
                     where cc.sid1 = abc.sid1
                    );
```

This will update all rows in `abc`.  If `sid1` does not match in the second table, then the value will remain `NULL`.

EDIT:

Your second table has multiple rows with the same value.  You need to figure out which one you want.  To choose an arbitrary one:

```
update abc
    set comp_code = (select cc.comp_code
                     from cc
                     where cc.sid1 = abc.sid1 and rownum = 1
                    );
```

You can also choose `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `LISTAGG()` or some other combination of values.

Comment: Smooth man. One hell of a solution. Great work! Thanks for help

Comment: @hashir. Merge would had been a better solution than this one. The problem was just your data not the statement. See updated anwer.

Comment: @XING This updates a single row only when i run it. No offence but the data is what it is.